# Estimation of lower bound of $\{k \alpha\}$ in range

Tags: real-analysis, computational-mathematics

It is well known that $\{k \alpha\}$ is dense in $[0, 1]$ when $k \in \mathbb{N}$, and $\alpha$ is an irrational number. Suppose we have $x \in [0, 1]$, and $\delta > 0$. The standard proof provides effective way to find $k_0$ such as $\exists k \in \mathbb{N}, k < k_0 \wedge \left\lvert x - \{k \alpha\} \right\rvert < \delta$.

Is there any efficient (better than brute force) way to find "non-trivial" $k_0$ that for  $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}, k < k_0 \Rightarrow \left\lvert x - \{k \alpha\} \right\rvert > \delta$. Effectively it provides lower boundary to hit the range. "Non-trivial" roughly means that it probably should grow as $\delta \rightarrow 0$. (We can exclude the case when $x = \{k \alpha \}$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$.)

Thank you!

Comment: It is derivable from the continued fraction expansion of $\alpha$, but the details are to complicated to fit here, and to fit in my memory.

Comment: I would be completely happy with reference to a textbook or an article. I understand the answer can be involved.

Comment: I read about it in this pay-wall protected paper: https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/gaps-and-steps-for-the-sequence-n-mod-1/D03A3F36A89E9E89D3F168CF855A0F73  which is cited by Kuipers and Niederreiter's book.

Comment: Thank you. Let me try to find it.